# Raw PHP code converted for use in CakePHP, new to cake

Tags: php, cakephp, input, http-post

I'm a total newbie to CakePHP, but I have a fairly ok grasp on the fundamentals of raw PHP. My problem is getting over the hump and learning how to conform to the CakePHP framework. I've read up on Cake and have done the examples, but the only way I'm going to learn this is to jump in head first and start coding something on my own. My question is, how do I convert something this simple into cake. IE what goes where, Controller/Model/View.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['guess'])) {
//my php 
};
?>

<form name="form" method="post" action="#">
Your guess: <input type="text" name="guess">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

All I want to do here is pass a number from user input to php (no database connection), run some php calculations, then return the results to the view. Do I have to use the form helper? It seems to center around database queries... And what goes where? From my angle, it seems cake may complicate such a simple snippet.

Much appreciated if someone could make some connections/relations to what I'm use to, and get me rolling.

Comment: For such a simple task, every Framework would be unnecessary. No matter if you use CakePHP, Laravel or something else. I have never worked with CakePHP, but the form has to be in the view while the PHP part belongs to the controller. The model is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Understood, but if someone could post some examples of breaking this stuff up, including the cake specifics commands would be outstanding. Sort of like comparing "English" to "Spanish", to get my brain connecting the links :) The issue I'm having are the examples are database related, and I just want to simply execute some code from input all on the same page. If I create a table for my inputs, then Cake starts to play nice. But then I start running into issues passing the data to my php in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to read CakePHP´s [Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html).

At first, create a **view** located in `app/View/Guess/create.ctp`:

```
// Using Form-Helper
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('guess'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); ?>
```

At second, create a **controller** located in `app/Controller/GuessController.php`:

```
class GuessController extends AppController
{
    // stop using a model
    public $uses = array();

    function create()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post', 'put'))
        {
            // now do something with your form data
            $doSomething = $this->request->data['Guess']['guess'];
        }
    }
}
```

That´s it.
Now you should call your action via url http://examplehost.com/Guess/create

At the beginning, CakePHP seems to be complicated, but it isn´t. I think, it is important to understand the MVC. That makes it easier to learn all common PHP-Frameworks.

At a first glance, a simple form like above might be implemented easier via pure php and html code. But if you want to do deeper tasks (e.g. validation, authentication, autorisation, security ...) and want to have a clean code, you will recognize the advantages of that framework.

Comment: Is it mandatory that the view be named create in this scenario?

Comment: Understood, but yes there is a much bigger picture to my madness, and the tutorials are not helping me like I would like.

Comment: @M-n: By CakePHP´s code convention the name of the action in your controller (that´s create) automatically matches to a template called `create.ctp`. For the convention it is mandatory. But if you want to render antoher view, you can define your different view in your action via `$this->render('viewname');`